# Can testers, administrators and developers add an app to their Timeline and publish actions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I have created a new app using Facebook's new Open Graph Beta and I can publish actions to my Timeline. So easy.

Developers, testers and administrators can click the Add to Timeline button and give permission but once the application is permitted, the Add to Timeline button won't go away and the tester or administrator can neither publish an action. Is it because Timelines are not public yet?

Currently, dev/testers/admins can see what I post (published actions) in my Timeline.